# OnClick Button Doesn't Work at Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got two buttons and they both work perfectly. Then, I needed both in some other page of my site and I simply copied and pasted the codes over there, buttons showed up but they don't work.

```
<input style="outline: none;" type="button" onclick="formatTextlink ('http://');" class="btn btn-default" value="link">

<input style="outline: none;" type="button" onclick="formatText ('bkz:');" class="btn btn-default" value="bkz:">
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: formatTextlink is not defined at
>   HTMLInputElement.onclick

Don't know really what to do. Any help is appreciated. Thank you already!

Comment: You also need to copy the JavaScript file or inline snippet that contains the `formatText()` and `formatTextLink()` functions. Events require an event handler...

Comment: `formatTextlink` function is not defined. Where is the JS?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your second HTML page has access to the Javascript that the first page was using? Seems to me that `formatText()` and `formatTextlink()` are user-defined somewhere and you might have forgotten to reference the appropriate JS file.

Comment: May be because you need to have `formatTextlink()` and `formatText()` methods in your second page too?

Comment: have you included your js file? looks like you didnt

Comment: @Yoda It could also mean the function named `formatTextlink()` was never defined. It doesn't necessarily mean the name is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught ReferenceError: formatTextlink is not defined this error occurs when the function you calling is not available in the page or error in the js script check whether the function is available else call the js having that funtion in the page where you need the function call

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught ReferenceError main simply that ***reference not found***.

Mains that formatTextlink is not defined in the current page. So you should reimport the .js where your functions are defined.

I suggest to put thos functions in a common file (for example, commonFunctions.js) and reimport this file when you need the two buttons.

> commonFunctions.js and Your page (example)

```js
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '[' + tag + '/]';
}

function formatTextlink(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '' + tag + '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="commonFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input style="outline: none;" type="button" onclick="formatTextlink ('http://');" class="btn btn-default" value="link">

<input style="outline: none;" type="button" onclick="formatText ('bkz:');" class="btn btn-default" value="bkz:">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sure forgot to include js codes in my second page. I had to add these following lines to get my buttons work. I thought that putting the js code once was enough to make all the buttons work, that was my mistake. So here's the solution, sorry and thanks everyone!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '[' + tag + '/]';
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formatTextlink(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '' + tag + '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have imported the JavaScript source code (where the functions are defined) in this page as well using either a `<script>` tag or a meta tag.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16898448)

Comment: It is neither a critique nor a request actually.